# Button appears in android API 19, but not API 17

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently, I'm using **Android 4.4.2(API 19)** to run my project and I can see all the layout works perfectly. But when I use another device **Android 4.2(API 17)**, the layout is running and some of the buttons did not show (footer layout) !!! How can I solve this? Did you guys face this problem before? Thanks.

**ListView Button**

These are the buttons in `xml` that did not show when I was using Android API 17. Just a normal button. They should show when there is a listView but they did not.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalHours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hours"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text=" Total Hours : "
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/submit"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/blue"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addClaims1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="submit"
        android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
        android:layout_width="334dp"
        android:layout_height="61dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/totalHours"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="add claims"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**Android 4.4.2(API 19)**

[image]

**Android 4.4.2(API 17)**

[image]

Comment: At first `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" & minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Sir I saw your first comment. Did I need to change anything in `build.gradle`?

Comment: @JohnJoe I just change `targetSdkVersion` . Rest of okay

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya thanks, but did you faced this before ? Layout running :(

Comment: @JohnJoe Actually `FrameLayout` is #too tricky . Run Project & let me inform .

Comment: @JohnJoe both buttons are not showing or one of them?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya an icon beside my button sir

Comment: @John Are you adding these buttons using listview.addFooterView method?

Comment: @JohnJoe Okay . Please set `android:layout_height="21dp"` instead of `android:layout_height="61dp"` . For testing case .

Comment: you can set `android:layout_marginTop="10dp"` instead of `sp` .Let me feedback

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya the two button can be shown now. Do you know how to adjust the two buttons ? Thanks

Comment: @JohnJoe I know ,Basically its xml problem . You need to rectify your xml .

Comment: @JohnJoe yes ,why not . Avoid hard-coded height value & use `android:layout_weight` logic

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya which line should I change ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101558/discussion-between-intellij-amiya-and-john-joe).

Comment: Don't change your question for another one, once you have an answer. Accept http://stackoverflow.com/a/34979225/94363 if you say it fixes your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call `addFooterView` before setting the adapter to the `ListView`.

**EDIT:**

Modify your code, such that you set the footerView before setting the adapter like this:

**Activity A**

```
footerLayout = (RelativeLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.under_list_view_button, null);
btnAddClaims = (Button) footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.addClaims1);
btnSubmit=(Button)footerLayout.findViewById(R.id.submit);
objMyCustomBaseAdapter = new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext(), results, listview, footerLayout);
addOrRemoveFooter(); 
listview.setAdapter(objMyCustomBaseAdapter); 

public void addOrRemoveFooter(){
if(results.size() == 0 && listview.getFooterViewsCount() > 0){
    // listview.removeFooterView(footer);
    listview.removeFooterView(footerLayout);
    }else if(listview.getFooterViewsCount() == 0 && results.size() > 0){
    // listview.addFooterView(footer);
    listview.addFooterView(footerLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I call it inside adapter

Comment: Move the `addOrRemoveFooter()` method before the `MyCustomBaseAdapter` initialization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101528/discussion-between-eric-b-and-john-joe).

Answer (score 3):

**Actually Its your XML Problem .You need to rectify your XML .**

**Why This Problem**

Problem is your `Button` Section .

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="334dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addClaims1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="submit"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
    android:layout_width="334dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/totalHours"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:text="add claims"/>
```

1. In your xml you added **hard-coded large value**,which are't showing
   small device .
2. **Avoid Hard-coded Value** . **`android:layout_height="61dp"`** & `android:layout_marginTop=10dp"` .

You can use **`layout_weight`** attribute .

> You can set a weight attribute using a float value for any view that
>   you use in a LinearLayout. Android will then divide the available
>   space up amongst the views proportionately, depending on their weight
>   values.

LinearLayout also supports assigning a weight to individual children with the **[android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)** attribute. This attribute assigns an `"importance"` value to a view in terms of how much space it should occupy on the screen.

A larger weight value allows it to expand to fill any remaining space in the parent view. Child views can specify a weight value, and then any remaining space in the view group is assigned to children in the proportion of their declared weight. Default weight is zero.

**Or You can use DisplayMetrics**

```
        /*
        * A structure describing general information about a display, such as its size, density, and font scaling.
        * */
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

        LinearLayout LL_First_Section=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout_Third_Invisible);
        LL_First_Section.getLayoutParams().width=DeviceTotalWidth; // Add your width 
        LL_First_Section.getLayoutParams().height= (DeviceTotalHeight*18/100);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) to show your buttons and force the `ListView` to take the remaining space.

---

**Try something like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalHours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/hours"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text=" Total Hours : "
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/submit"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="334dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:text="submit"
            android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addClaims1"
            android:layout_width="334dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/totalHours"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="add claims"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both left|start and right|end to get support for all the api levels. 
For example I am showing 1 Button of your layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit"
    android:layout_width="334dp"
    android:layout_height="61dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addClaims1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:text="submit"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```